# Controller method not found

Tags: php, laravel-4

I have a form which has some values that I am trying to edit. Below is the controller.

```
<?php 

class GSchedulesController extends \BaseController {

protected $quoteRepo;


public function __construct(QuoteRepository $quoteRepo)
{
    $this->quoteRepo = $quoteRepo;
}

public function destroy()
{
    $quote = $this->quoteRepo->randomQuotes()->take(1);
    $schedule = GSchedule::all()->first();

    return View::make('adminsection.schedules.edit')->with('schedule',$schedule)->with('quote',$quote);

}

public function create()
{
    $quote = $this->quoteRepo->randomQuotes()->take(1);
    $schedule = GSchedule::all()->first();

    return View::make('adminsection.schedules.edit')->with('schedule',$schedule)->with('quote',$quote);

}

public function store()
{
    $quote = $this->quoteRepo->randomQuotes()->take(1);
    $schedule = GSchedule::first();

    return View::make('adminsection.schedules.edit')->with('schedule',$schedule)->with('quote',$quote);

}

public function index()
 {
    $quote = $this->quoteRepo->randomQuotes()->take(1);

    $schedule = GSchedule::first();
    return View::make('adminsection.schedules.edit')->with('schedule',$schedule)->with('quote',$quote);
 }

public function scheduleadmin()
 {
    $quote = $this->quoteRepo->randomQuotes()->take(1);

    $schedule = GSchedule::first();
    return View::make('adminsection.schedules.edit')->with('schedule',$schedule)->with('quote',$quote);
 }


 public function edit()
 {
    $quote = $this->quoteRepo->randomQuotes()->take(1);

    $schedule = GSchedule::find($id);
    return View::make('adminsection.schedules.edit')->withSchedule($schedule)->with('quote',$quote);
 }



  public function udpate($id)
  {
    $quote = $this->quoteRepo->randomQuotes()->take(1);

    $input = array_except(Input::all(), '_method');

    $schedule = GSchedule::first();
    $schedule->fill($input);
    $schedule->save();
    $schedule = GSchedule::first();
    return Redirect::to('adminsection.schedules.edit')->withSchedule($schedule)->with('quote',$quote);
  }  

 public function scheduleudpate($id)
 {
    dd(' i am here');
    $quote = $this->quoteRepo->randomQuotes()->take(1);

    $input = array_except(Input::all(), '_method');

    $schedule = GSchedule::all()->first();

    $schedule->fill($input);
    $schedule->save();
    $schedule = GSchedule::all()->first();
    return Redirect::to('adminsection.schedules.edit')->withSchedule($schedule)->with('quote',$quote);
     }
}
```

and my route look like this

> Route::resource('schedules', 'GSchedulesController');

so whenever I am refering a url like this

> `http://localhost:8000/schedules/1`

I am getting a Controller method not found. exception..

**Please Note :** The intended form should always be in the edit mode. Clicking on Save should update the record. there is only one record in the database that will be updated and displayed to the user (kind of a settings form )

**Note 1:**  I have now updated my controller with the show method but I am still getting the ControllerNotFound exception whenever I am trying to update my entity .

```
    public function show($id)
{
    $quote = $this->quoteRepo->randomQuotes()->take(1);
    $schedule = GSchedule::first();

    return View::make('adminsection.schedules.edit')->with('schedule',$schedule)->with('quote',$quote);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Moving this to an actual answer. :)*

Looks like you're missing the 'show' method, and your update function has a typo in the name. Also your 'edit' function needs to take in $id.

Just return redirecting to your edit method in the show method. For example:

```
public function show($id)
{
    return Redirect::route('adminsection.schedules.edit', $id);
}
```

That way if you want to add one later you can.

Comment: Still getting the same message - I have updated the question with what I have done

Comment: spoke too soon - sorry it worked - the 'udpate' was the culprit :) - marking this as the answer

Answer (score 0):

http://laravel.com/docs/controllers#resource-controllers

When you visit /resource/{id}, the method `show($id)` is called - which you don't have.

Comment: Still getting the same message - I have updated the question with what I have done